# JavaScript parse error at line (345) column (62) problem = invalid property id (<refname>; line 345)

Tags: javascript, parsing, servicenow, parse-error

I keep getting a parse error on this line but I'm not sure what to parse since this is a variable declaration

```
var dp =   element.find('.input-group-btn').datetimepicker({<br>       keepInvalid: true,<br>       pickTime: scope.snIncludeTime === true,<br>       format: scope.format,<br>       locale: g_lang,<br>       sideBySide:   true,<br>       language: g_lang<br>   }).on('dp.change', onDpChange);
```

This was the original line that I configured:

var dp = element.find('.input-group-btn').datetimepicker(config).on('dp.change', onDpChange);

I keep getting this error: 
JavaScript parse error at line (345) column (62) problem = invalid property id (; line 345)

Comment: Can you please be more specific what are you trying to achieve and may be a more expicit snippet would help.

Comment: Also your code is formatted incorrectly; I suspect those `<br>` elements are intended to format the code itself.

Comment: That is not a native error message, what is the used framework?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that is how your code looks? If that was not a copy paste mistake, those `<br>` shouldn't be there.